# How to replicate Team Explorer's Toolbar for my own VS-extension (is the source code available)?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, vspackage, team-explorer

I'd like to create a Visual Studio 2013 Extension with toolbars in its windows - those should be roughly the same as Team Explorer's Toolbar.
So I wondered if its source code is available somewhere so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel if it's not really needed.
So far I only created the sample toolbar of [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx).

Comment: You can use artwork from the Image Library http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to create a toolbar inside your toolwindow, see [Walkthrough: Adding a Toolbar to a Tool Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164714.aspx)

If you mean to replicate the Team Explorer buttons actions, you have lots of "tfs" commands ("Tools" >"Options" window, "Environment" > "Keyboard" section, "Show commands containing" list) that you can execute programmatically, either by command full name or by command guid/id ([HOWTO: Execute a command by Guid and Id from a Visual Studio package](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/)).